# div aligned to the right: incorrect scrollbar

Tags: html, css, web

I have the markup like this:

```
<div id="MainDiv" style="position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <div id="Log" style="float: right; max-height:100%; overflow: scroll;">
        (some filling text)
    </div>
</div>
```

It works ok, except the fact that only half of Log's vertical scrollbar is shown (FF, Chrome).
Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost definitely because the body has a margin. Remove that and it should work.

```
body
{
    margin:0;
}
```

Here's the JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/ajicox/1/

Comment: Okay, this solves the problem. But for me it looks like a bug in browser.

Comment: Not at all, it's just a default style combined with how CSS works (admittedly it has some major flaws). You may also want to set padding to 0, and set them both on html as well as body - different browsers may implement it differently.

Comment: But what if I _do_ need margin around MainDiv?

Comment: Then you can instead of setting width or height, set top, left, bottom, AND right, to the values you want for your margin. And if you want padding as well, it will just work then too. Here's an updated jsbin: http://jsbin.com/emuteg/2

Comment: If you only wanted padding, and you still wanted to use width and height for some reason, another method (which would only work for padding, not actually margin) would be to use box-sizing, which you can read about here: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Answer (score 0):

You have to set padding to 0 also. different browsers have different settings.

> body {
>       margin:0;
>       padding:0; }

```
Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ngkam/
```